# How to add two html scripts in a single blogger post?

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I have my own blog in blogger and I am a content provider. I use a content locking code for my certain download links in my blogger posts. It was all going on well until I stumbled upon this. In one post there was more than two download links and I tried adding the same script again. The script actually is a Subscribe to Unlock script and the viewers need to subscribe to unlock the link. I have attached my code below. The problem arises when I add the same code again to my post, the youtube link of my channel which should actually open in a new tab, does not open in a new tab whereas it opens in the same tab! This does not allow my viewers to unlock the content as the post closes and youtube opens. Also this problem does not occur with the first yt content locker but only from the second one and continues. Pleae help me solve this problem. Also I am not any good coder or have any knowledge about coding. So please make answer simplified. Below I have attached my YouTube Content Locker Code.

```html
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <style>
        @import "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css";
        html, body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
        #sociallocker {
            background-color: #EEEEEE;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            max-width: 500px;
            height: 120px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-radius:10px;
        }
        #sociallocker-overlay {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ffffff;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
        }
        #sociallocker-overlay i {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        #sociallocker:hover #sociallocker-overlay {
            top: -100%;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
        }
        #sociallocker:hover #sociallocker-content {
            top: 100%;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
        }
        #sociallocker-content a {
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            background-color: #777777;
            color: #f9f9f9;
            border-radius: 4px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        #sociallocker-overlay,
        #sociallocker-content,
        #sociallocker-links{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        #sociallocker-content {
            background-color: #ccc;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
        }
        .social-1 {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 498px;
            height: 118px;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-right: 0px;
        }
        .social-1 i {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .social-1:hover i {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            transform: scale(1.2);
            transition: all 0.2s;
        }
        .fb { background-color: #FF0000; }
</style>
        <div id="sociallocker">
            <div id="sociallocker-links">
                <a class="social-1 fb" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqUX2UrWUz778zSFxPtVRyw?sub_confirmation=1"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div id="sociallocker-content">
                <a href="DOWNLOAD LINK HERE" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-download"></i> Download</a>
            </div>
            <div id="sociallocker-overlay"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i>SUBSCRIBE TO UNLOCK</div>
        </div>
        <script>
        (function() {
            var sl = document.querySelector("#sociallocker");
            var slc = document.querySelector("#sociallocker-content");
            if (!sl) return;
            var old_slc_html = slc.innerHTML;
            slc.innerHTML = slc.innerHTML.replace(/(href=")(.*)(\")/g, "href=\"#\"");
            sl.querySelectorAll("#sociallocker-links a").forEach(function(ele) {
                ele.onclick = function(e) {
                    var web_window = window.open(this.href, 'Share Link', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600,top=' + (screen.height/2 - 300) + ',left=' + (screen.width/2 - 300));
                    var check_window_close = setInterval(function() { 
                        if (web_window.closed) {
                            clearInterval(check_window_close);
                            slc.innerHTML = old_slc_html;
                            document.querySelector("#sociallocker-links").style.display = "none";
                            document.querySelector("#sociallocker-overlay").style.display = "none"; 
                            document.querySelector("#sociallocker-content").style.top = "0";
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                    e.preventDefault();
                };
            });
        })();
        </script>
```

Comment: It opens fine in a new window for me
https://jsfiddle.net/vanowm/5gvb7caL/

Comment: Hey I am saying that if I use this content lock just once in my post it opens in a new tab. Assume that I have added the same content locker for in two more places in my blog. Now when I click upon the first content locker, the YouTube subscribe opens correctly in a new popup tab. But when I click on the 2nd & 3rd content locker which I had added in the same post, the YouTube subscribe opens in the same page, thereby not closing the page which the person is viewing. Hence he/she cannot unlock the content at all. Hope I have clearly explained my problem.

Comment: Man thanks a lot ! It works like a charm. Although I don't exactly understand what the problem is and how you have resolved it, I just understood that there were two same ID's which were clashing. Anyways thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that locker uses `id` and `id` must be unique, but when you create multiple copy of the locker, these `id` are conflicting. Because of that the javascript portion of the locker set up event listeners only on first locker.

To fix that, you'll need convert all `id` and references to it into css classes, than you can use single javascript for all:

https://jsfiddle.net/vanowm/5gvb7caL/

```html
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <style>
        @import "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css";
        html, body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
        .sociallocker {
            background-color: #EEEEEE;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            max-width: 500px;
            height: 120px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-radius:10px;
        }
        .sociallocker-overlay {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ffffff;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
        }
        .sociallocker-overlay i {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .sociallocker:hover .sociallocker-overlay {
            top: -100%;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
        }
        .sociallocker:hover .sociallocker-content {
            top: 100%;
            transition: all 0.2s linear;
        }
        .sociallocker-content a {
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            background-color: #777777;
            color: #f9f9f9;
            border-radius: 4px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .sociallocker-overlay,
        .sociallocker-content,
        .sociallocker-links{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        .sociallocker-content {
            background-color: #ccc;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
        }
        .social-1 {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 498px;
            height: 118px;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-right: 0px;
        }
        .social-1 i {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .social-1:hover i {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            transform: scale(1.2);
            transition: all 0.2s;
        }
        .fb { background-color: #FF0000; }
</style>
<!-- first locker !-->
        <div class="sociallocker">
            <div class="sociallocker-links">
                <a class="social-1 fb" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqUX2UrWUz778zSFxPtVRyw?sub_confirmation=1"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="sociallocker-content">
                <a href="DOWNLOAD LINK HERE" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-download"></i> Download</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sociallocker-overlay"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i>SUBSCRIBE TO UNLOCK</div>
        </div>

<!-- second locker !-->
        <div class="sociallocker">
            <div class="sociallocker-links">
                <a class="social-1 fb" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqUX2UrWUz778zSFxPtVRyw?sub_confirmation=1"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="sociallocker-content">
                <a href="DOWNLOAD LINK HERE" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-download"></i> Download</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sociallocker-overlay"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i>SUBSCRIBE TO UNLOCK</div>
        </div>

<!-- third locker !-->
        <div class="sociallocker">
            <div class="sociallocker-links">
                <a class="social-1 fb" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqUX2UrWUz778zSFxPtVRyw?sub_confirmation=1"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="sociallocker-content">
                <a href="DOWNLOAD LINK HERE" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-download"></i> Download</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sociallocker-overlay"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i>SUBSCRIBE TO UNLOCK</div>
        </div>
<!-- end locker !-->

        <script>
        (function() {
            var sls = document.querySelectorAll(".sociallocker");
            sls.forEach(sl =>
            {
              var slc = sl.querySelector(".sociallocker-content");
              if (!sl) return;
              var old_slc_html = slc.innerHTML;
              slc.innerHTML = slc.innerHTML.replace(/(href=")(.*)(\")/g, "href=\"#\"");
              sl.querySelectorAll(".sociallocker-links a").forEach(function(ele) {
                  ele.onclick = function(e) {
                      var web_window = window.open(this.href, 'Share Link', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600,top=' + (screen.height/2 - 300) + ',left=' + (screen.width/2 - 300));
                      var check_window_close = setInterval(function() { 
                          if (web_window.closed) {
                              clearInterval(check_window_close);
                              slc.innerHTML = old_slc_html;
                              sl.querySelector(".sociallocker-links").style.display = "none";
                              sl.querySelector(".sociallocker-overlay").style.display = "none"; 
                              sl.querySelector(".sociallocker-content").style.top = "0";
                          }
                      }, 1000);
                      e.preventDefault();
                  };
              });
            });
        })();
        </script>
```

Comment: Hey I am saying that if I use this content lock just once in my post it opens in a new tab. Assume that I have added the same content locker for in two more places in my blog. Now when I click upon the first content locker, the YouTube subscribe opens correctly in a new popup tab. But when I click on the 2nd & 3rd content locker which I had added in the same post, the YouTube subscribe opens in the same page, thereby not closing the page which the person is viewing. Hence he/she cannot unlock the content at all. Hope I have clearly explained my problem.

Comment: @KnightPhotoshop I've updated my answer and code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quit sure I understand you, but what I understand is you saying that it's opening in the same tab and that you want it to open in a different tab.  `window.open(this.href, 'Share Link'...` needs to be `window.open(this.href, '_blank'...`, otherwise it will open in the same tab.  The second argument to that function ('Share Link' or '_blank') specifies the window name but if you pass '_blank' to it it tells the window to open in a new tab.

Comment: actually, it will open in a new tab, and will reuse that tab again for the next popup. If that tab closed, it will open in a new tab again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, isn't that what you want, for it to open in a new tab?

Comment: yes, but in some cases it's preferable reuse previously opened tab. i.e. if you have different links to different search engines, so it would open all links to google in tab1 and links to bing in tab2 instead of opening 10 different tabs. So in OPs case, it's probably preferable reuse previously opened tab for the next "subscribe" click rather than have 2 different tabs opened.

Comment: Hey could you guys be more specific ? As I said I don't know even abcd about codes and html

Comment: I have tried all your methods but none of them seem to be working. I have added below more details of my problem.

Comment: Hey I am saying that if I use this content lock just once in my post it opens in a new tab. Assume that I have added the same content locker for in two more places in my blog. Now when I click upon the first content locker, the YouTube subscribe opens correctly in a new popup tab. But when I click on the 2nd & 3rd content locker which I had added in the same post, the YouTube subscribe opens in the same page, thereby not closing the page which the person is viewing. Hence he/she cannot unlock the content at all. Hope I have clearly explained my problem.